# loop that continuously goes back and forth

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have an infinite loop that goes back and forth through an array, the function that I have goes forward and I want it to go backward once i = array.length.
here's my code:

```js
    var myArray = ["banana", "apple", "peer", "grape"]

    var i = 0;
    
    (function loop() {
        console.log(myArray[i])
        if(i++ < myArray.length-1){
            setTimeout(loop, 1000);
        }
    })();
```

I'm missing the backward part because what I tried didn't work,

Any help will really be appreciated

Comment: Odd problem but whatever. When you hit the last element, should it double it on the way back or skip it? For example, when you output banana, apple, peer (pear?), grape, should the next item output be grape again or peer (pear?)?

Comment: You could use a `while` loop instead, manually set the index and then just change the direction once the index reaches 0 or `myArray.length - 1`.

Comment: @j08691 yeah i'ts pear ^^ 
my expected output is : banana, apple, pear, grape, pear, apple, banana, apple, pear, grape, ... and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that reverses the array when it hits the length:

```js
var myArray = ["banana", "apple", "pear", "grape"];
var i = 0;
(function loop() {
  if (i < (myArray.length - 1)) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    i++;
  } else {
    myArray.reverse();
    i = 0;
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    i = 1;
  }
  setTimeout(loop, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you're looking for.  I haven't run it in anything so there may be some errors, but it should give you a gist of what you're aiming for.

```
const myArray = ["banana", "apple", "peer", "grape"];
let index = 0;
let direction = 0;
const maxLoops = 50;
let loopCount = 0;

while (loopCount < maxLoops) {
    console.log(myArray[index]);
    if (direction === 0) {
        index++;
    } else {
        index--;
    }


    if (direction === 0 && index >= myArray.length - 1) {
        direction = 1;
    } else if (direction === 1 && index <= 0) {
        direction = 0;
    }

    loopCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that counts up then down, etc.

```
var i = 0;
var maxIndex = 9;
var dir = 1;

while(true)
{
    if (i == maxIndex*dir) dir = !dir;

    doSomething(i);

    i += (dir<<1)-1;
}
```